# Кроме того (,) как

Tags: запятые

В каких случаях нужно поставить запятую? Есть следующие примеры из интернета:

У вас нет другого выхода, кроме того как отпустить меня.

У Тома нет выхода, кроме того, как уйти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***У Тома нет выхода, кроме того как уйти.***

Сочетание ***кроме того как***  по смыслу соответствует сочетанию  ***кроме как***, а это сочетание используется в качестве ограничительного союза.

Из словаря: ***<Кроме как***, в зн. союза. Употр. для ограничения какого-л. отрицания; только, разве что. ***Нигде этой книги не найдёшь, кроме как в спецхране.***

**Сравнить:**

Том не понял ничего, ***кроме того, что*** он должен уйти. Том не понял ***ничего, кроме того,*** как ему не следует поступать.

В этих примерах союз ЧТО относится к придаточному предложению.